# Get data filtering by local timezone from UTC

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

We have an application in Laravel 5.2. In our database, published_at stores date in timestamp with carbon instance in UTC, just as created_at and updated_at.

Every post is supposed to be published at midnight in every timezone. We saved our dates data in UTC format, like

```
'published_at' => '2016-04-12 00:00:00'
```

What we want to do is like;

if a person in US views it, then he/she sees that post after his/her midnight time. If a person in China views it, then he/she sees that post after his/her midnight time. How can we achieve this?

This is what we are doing at the moment. But, we think it's not gonna work.

```
    public function all($limit, array $data = [])
    {
        $posts = $this->post->with('categories')
            ->where(
                'published_at', Carbon::now()->setTimezone($data['user_timezone'])
                                             ->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00')
            )
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'ASC')
            ->paginate($limit);
    }
```

This is the first time we are working in timezones and we have no idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do a "sequential timezone publish", where over the course of 24 hours, it's midnight somewhere.

Assuming you've grabbed the timezone from input somewhere (in `$data`?), you can use the standard Eloquent / Laravel Query Builder verbiage to construct the query you require:

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

```
    public function all($limit, array $data = [])
    {
        $posts = $this->post->with('categories')
            ->where(
                'published_at',
                '<',
                Carbon::now($data['user_timezone'])
                    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            )
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'ASC')
            ->paginate($limit);
    }
```

That way as soon as "midnight" has occurred in the timezone being passed through, the `"published_at"` will have a value of "less than" the current timestamp, including it in the results.

Comment: Great. That's what we are looking for. Thank you. Also, when we are trying to get today's post, then we are replacing the where() clause part with whereBetween() clause like 
    
`whereBetween( 'published_at', array( Carbon::now($data['timezone'])->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), Carbon::now($data['timezone'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) )` . Will this work?

Comment: @IamGhale you can shorten it to `whereBetween('published_at', [Carbon::now($data['timezone']),Carbon::tomorrow($data['timezone'])])`